# XAMPP - MySQL will not start unless deleting aria.log first

Tags: mariadb, xampp

I have eventually found a work around to start MySQl after lots of research.
Lots of suggestions to delete the data folder and then reinstate from the backup folder, which worked.
What I found was that it seems the aria.log is causing the MySQL issue. Although just deleting the file prior to firing up XAMPP works, Its annoying and I would like to find out if I could fix this issue permanently?
Has anybody encountered this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: What does your MariaDB (its not MySQL despite XAMPP's perpetual bad naming) log say? Deleting files is a good way to loose data, MariaDB doesn't create them for your deleting pleasure.

Comment: Thanks for your sarcastic comment Dan. It is actually a known issue and all related topics recommend deleting the parent folder (data) and then and then reinstating form the sibling folder marked "backup". I wonder why its called 'backup'?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please share how this problem is related to programming. As far as I see, it might be more on-topic on serverfault.com